# My Unity application is on the left side

Tags: unity, 2d

Today I made a Unity 2D app with a square moving around and I wanted to know why is the alignment on the left.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Game seen from the play preview]

[image: Game seen from the visual editor]

[image: Game seen from the built file]

Comment: It could be a problem with how you set up your [Camera component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html). Did you perhaps mess with the viewport rect?

Comment: @Philipp yes, i did

Comment: @Philipp guess i have to change the x and y because i changed w and h

Answer (score 0):

I set my camera viewport viewport rect to W 0.5 and H 1.
I had to change the X to half of W.
So if you change the W then you need to change your X to half of W, and if you change the H then you need to change Y to half of H for the viewport to be aligned in the middle.